# Force Embedded .wav files in Latex Document to be played using wave-surfer

Tags: beamer, pdftex, media9, multimedia

I have few .wav files embedded in a latex pdf document. By default, they are played in some music player in windows during presentation. However i want to force them to be played using wave-surfer, so that i can see interactive plot options provided by wave-surfer.

Answer (score 1):

I am using Mac OS, but I think the solution is quite similar. You have to change the default program Windows associates with a .WAV-file and change it to wave-surfer, cf. https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/307859